# MP3 Mixing program

Tags: software-recommendation, music, mp3

Is there a mixing program that exist for mixing mp3/wav files like for example VirtualDJ or Tracktor for Linux Ubuntu?

Comment: You might try lmms

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Try Mixxx (http://www.mixxx.org/).

I have used Mixxx on several radio gigs and at home. Works great and stable even after hours of mixing.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Actually, I would advise to use Mixxx` PPA since the version in the Ubuntu repositories usually outdates very quickly. 

It already is. Mixxx is now 1.11. Ubuntu package is 1.10.1. Which is not bad, but usually the PPA is well tested and comes with more speed and functions. Remember, Mixxx is a tool for live perfomances, so it has to be rock-solid. And the folks over there are delivering this stability. So there is no reason not to use the PPA.

Answer (score 2):

> Audacity is a multi-track audio editor for Linux/Unix, MacOS and
>   Windows. It is designed for easy recording, playing and editing of
>   digital audio. Audacity features digital effects and spectrum analysis
>   tools. Editing is very fast and provides unlimited undo/redo.
>
> Supported file formats include Ogg Vorbis, MP2, MP3, WAV, AIFF, and
>   AU.<sup>1</sup>

For more information on Audacity, check out the [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) web site.

To install Audacity, just click on the image below.

[image: Install via the software center]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity/)</sup>